# Flies without wings

Tags: species-identification, entomology

some time ago I spotted a wingless fly in my small garden. I thought to myself that it's rather weird and most likely just a random thing. But after some time I spotted more wingless flies and just a minute ago I took a photo of one specimen: [image]

You can see that it also lacks a leg. The sightings were separated with at least few days each (I wasn't paying too much attention at first), so I think it's very unlikely it's a same fly, because spiders and ants would probably hunt it down long time ago. Unfortunately it's the only documentation I currently have although I'll try to get more. Does anyone know what could be the cause?

Comment: I just saw two today! It's strange honestly, I just thought it was some weird wingless flies. First time I saw them and I laughed  I think they're called Wingless Solider Flies.

Comment: louse flies are known to drop their wings after they find an animal to lay their eggs on,i am not saying that it is a louse flie as they have a very flat body.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include as much of the following essential information as possible to improve your chances of getting a good answer: 1) one or more clear closeup photos of the organism (photos from multiple angles if possible)); 2) the location (e.g. country and region — the more specific the better) where you observed this organism; 3) habitat information; and 4) an estimate of the size of the organism. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site.

Comment: It would help a lot if we knew where you are, many islands have wingless flies for instance.